# AngularJS document.write() won't work in partial

Tags: angularjs

I want to include the current year in the copy-write notice in the footer of AngularJS app I'm building with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
```

The problem is when I try to add it in a partial that has been added to document with `ng-include` it won't work:

```
<footer ng-include="'app/static/partials/footer.html'" class="main"></footer>
```

It works when I add it directly to `index.html`.  What is the best way to achieve this in AngularJS?

Do I need to turn the footer into a directive and add a controller for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a scope variable in your footer's controller. e.g. `$scope.year = new Date().getFullYear();` then you can use it in your HTML like this: `{{year}}`.

It need not be a directive. You can also use `ng-controller="footerCtrl"` etc. as an HTML property for your footer to point to the controller you want to use for your footer.

Comment: Wanted to also mention that technically your copyright date will at some point be legally incorrect, if you say launch your site this month and make no improvements when January rolls around, you'll see 2017 instead of the correct value of 2016.

Comment: I thought it was normal practice to display the current year i.e date of latest revision which is the current year for most maintained websites.  http://updateyourfooter.com

Comment: If you're working on a website with constantly changing daily content (user-generated etc.) where the ownership of the content is with the site's owners, then it'd make sense to have the copyright update. e.g. (C) 2012-2016, XYZ Inc. All rights reserved. (2016 would auto-change to 2017.) If it's content that is rarely updated and only via published releases, such as a static site you write for a client, it shouldn't auto-change to be a date later than the creation of the last content.